# PHP Show/hide link

Tags: php, mysql

I have a function that prints out articles from my database and three links Edit , Add , Show/hide.
In the show/hide link i want to be able to hide/show that particular article.
How can i do that? 
EDIT: I need to be able to hide/show articles in my backend page and it needs to stay hidden in the frontend page

```
function displaynews()
{
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news")  // query
    or die(mysql_error());   
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
    {
        $id = $info['id']; 
        echo "<br>
              <a href=Edit.php?id=$id>Edit</a></a>
              <a href='addnews.php'> Add </a>
              <a href='#'>Show/Hide</a><br><strong>" .
              $info['date'] .
              "</strong><br>" . 
              $info['news_content'] . 
              "<hr><br>"; // Print Articles and Date
    }
}
```

Comment: using jquery like this: $('.something').hide();

Comment: Be sure to up vote or mark the answer to the response that best solves your problem ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could use some Javascript and set the style attribute to display:none to hide, then display:block to show it again. Or use jQuery.

Comment: I assume i then would have to put all the articles in div tags?

Comment: Or you could put that particular line inside of a span tag and refer to its ID and do the same thing. Either way you go.. setting display to none or block is the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery.

```
<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head>

<a href='#' onclick="$('#whatever').toggle();return false;">show/hide</a>
<div id="whatever">
  Content
</div>
<script>
 //Try these too
$('#whatever').hide();
$('#whatever').show();
$('#whatever').toggle();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

**PHP Code:**

```
function displaynews()
{
    $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news")  // query
    or die(mysql_error());   
    while ($info = mysql_fetch_array($data)) 
    {
        $id = $info['id']; 
        echo "<div class="news"><br><a href=Edit.php?id=$id>Edit</a></a><a href='addnews.php'> Add </a><a href=hide.php>Show/Hide</a><br><strong>". $info['date']."</strong><br>". $info['news_content'] . "<hr><br></div>"; // Print Articles and Date
    }
}
```

**Javascript/jQuery Code** (Don't forget to add jQuery in your page)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".news").click(function(){
  $(this).toggle();
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: If i do this in my backend page will the article stay hidden in the frontend page?